# CSS3 (Drop down menu) second Sub-menu doesn't appear

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, submenu

I am trying to make a nice looking drop down menu. I searched a bit for tutorials and all, and I found some good ones. The main menu and the first sub-menu work well, but the second sub-menu doesn't show up when my mouse is over it.

Here's my html's structure:

```
<body>
    <ul class="menu">

        <li><a href="#" class="home">Acceuil</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="LoL">LoL</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a><span class="headlist">League of Legends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Funny moments</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Favorite builds</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">...</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="ssf2">SSF2</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a><span class="headlist">Super Smash Flash 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Challenges</a></li>
            </ul>
        <li><a href="#">RotMG</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Documents</a></li>

    </ul>
</body>
```

And this is my CSS build:

```
.menu,
.menu ul,
.menu li,
.menu a,
.menu p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: none;
outline: none;
}

/* Menu */ 
.menu {
height: 40px;
width: 610px; 

background: #760101;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#D20202, #760101); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #760101),color-stop(1, #D20202));    
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#D20202, #760101);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#D20202, #760101);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#D20202, #760101);
background: linear-gradient(#D20202, #760101);

-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 13px;

display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

.menu li {
position: relative;
list-style: none;
float: left;
display: block;
height: 40px;
}

.menu li a {
display: block;
padding: 0 7px 0 40px;
margin: 6px 0;
line-height: 28px;
text-decoration: none;

border-left: 1px solid #4B0101;
border-right: 1px solid #5C0101;

font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 13px;

color: #f3f3f3;
text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.6);

-webkit-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
transition: color .2s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li:first-child a { border-left: none; }
.menu li:last-child a{ border-right: none; }

.menu li:hover > a { color: #FF9900; }

/* Sub-menu */

.menu ul {
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
left: 0;

opacity: 0;
background: #D20202;
background: -moz-linear-gradient(#760101, #D20202); 
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left bottom,left top,color-stop(0, #D20202),color-stop(1, #760101));    
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#760101, #D20202);  
background: -o-linear-gradient(#760101, #D20202);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(#760101, #D20202);
background: linear-gradient(#760101, #D20202);

-webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;

-webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
transition: opacity .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul { opacity: 1; }

.menu ul li {
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 0;

-webkit-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-moz-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-o-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
-ms-transition: height .25s ease .1s;
transition: height .25s ease .1s;
}

.menu li:hover > ul li {
height: 36px;
overflow: visible;
padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li a {
width: 135px;
padding: 4px 0 4px 10px;
margin: 0;

border: none;
border-bottom: 1px solid #4B0101;
}

.menu ul li:last-child a { 
border: none; 
}

.LoL
{
background: url(LoLicon.png) no-repeat 6px center;
}

.home
{
background: url(home.png) no-repeat 6px center;
}

.ssf2
{
background: url(SSF2.png) no-repeat 6px center;
}

.headlist
{
color:#ff9900;
}

.menu ul li:first-child a { 
border-bottom: 3px solid #4B0101; 
}
```

Answers are welcome!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k2qUT/ - Fiddle instantly made with http://stackapps.com/questions/4228/fiddle-it-instant-fiddles-userscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a error here:

```
 <li><a href="#" class="ssf2">SSF2</a></li>
            <ul>
                <li><a><span class="headlist">Super Smash Flash 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Challenges</a></li>
            </ul>
```

it should be:

```
 <li><a href="#" class="ssf2">SSF2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a><span class="headlist">Super Smash Flash 2</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Intro</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Challenges</a></li>
            </ul>
</li>
```

here is a [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/tugSa/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will be able to continue!! :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap your li around the sub-nav ul.

You can't just chuck a ul in a ul.

It goes ul > li > ul > li

That's part of your problem.

Edit: Also, get rid of all those browser-prefixes.  Those things are bad news.  Pretty much anything cool you want to do with your CSS, all modern browsers support.  There are exceptions.  This site is your friend: http://caniuse.com/

If a browser doesn't support something you're doing, my suggestion is to make it work in that browser, but as far as it looking awesome - not necessary.  They have an old/bad browser.  They are used to things not looking awesome.

Comment: jycr753 found the error in my html code, but thanks for the site, it will surely help me! :)

Comment: ...we said the same thing.  I said it two minutes earlier.  Now I'm going to go and pout like a big baby.